# Notification update from a service when app is closed?

Tags: android, service, notifications, updates, foreground

I am learning services (and android) with the Pedometer of this web:

https://github.com/nintendaii/unity-background-service

Unity create a service in android that counts the steps done.

I am trying to have a notification updated with the last steps done. Its work perfect when app is open or suspended in background, but when i close it, thought the service continues counting steps, the notification update dont work.

Looking debug i see that the activity that creates Unity go null when the app is close. I am looking in internet and dont know if the thing i am trying is possible (using the original service with my changes).

This is the notification update system. Bridge is a class that can communicate with other app (Unity) and have the activity reference (myActivity):

```
private Notification crearNotificacion()
{
    String input = "Pasos: " + (Bridge.steps);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Bridge.myActivity.getClass());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "PedometerLib")
            .setContentTitle("Background Walking Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    return notification;
}
```

And the notify method:

```
notificationManager.notify(112, crearNotificacion());
```

If i try to use the original line with:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Bridge.myActivity.getClass());
```

*I have a Null pointer excepction (no activity).*

If i try to dont use activities like i see in other web:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    getApplicationContext(),
    0,
    new Intent(), // add this
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I have errors in the notify method:

*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat.notify(int, android.app.Notification)' on a null object reference*

Any hint? I need more complex code to make this?

Comment: Can you post the Android version in that you are facing issue ?

Comment: Android 11 in a samsung S20 FE

Comment: Then I am sure that It is woring in lower than Android 10 devies. Because with Android 10 and 11 There are restriction on doing some work in background. Chech this -> https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services and https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/foreground-services

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Bridge.myActivity.getClass());
```

The problem is that you use the instance of your activity to get its‘ class but the activity will not be instantiated if the app is destroyed and the service running in the background.

You can get the class like this:

```
 Intent(this, YourActivityName.class);
```

Comment: The problem is that i havent got that activity in the Android application/service. The class is "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" and is created by unity and passed to service from Unity.

Comment: When you include the library into your project and build it you should be able to import the class into your class: Intent(this, UnityPlayerActivity.class)

Comment: Cant do that. The UnitPlayerActivity have references to classes of UnityAndroid. If i include UnityPlayerActivity in the android projec, i need this libraries to compile. If i include the libraries, i can compile the android project. But then Unity dont compile because find duplicates libraries

Comment: Which activity you want to open, if a user clicks the notification?

Comment: I am testing these days creating a neutral activity to the service. These seems to work, but i lose the relation to the main App, so the user cant open de original app clicking the notification.